Calculating integral with DCT but got a weird result
I am calculating an integral $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]}\sqrt{n}(1-x^2)^n\mathrm{d}x$$
Note it's even function so I only needs to calculate the value $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}\sqrt{n}(1-x^2)^n\mathrm{d}x$. I led $t=\sqrt{n}x\in[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]$, it becomes
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{n}\right)^{n}\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]}f_{n}(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
By inequality $\ln(1-\frac{t^2}{n})\leq-\frac{t^2}{n}$ I got $|f_{n}(t)|\leq e^{-t^2}=g(t)$. And $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(t)=e^{-t^2}$. Since $g(t)$ is integrable and by dominated convergence theorem, the integration and limit symbol can exchange. Hence,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]}f_{n}(t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_{[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]}e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$$
But it's error function, so I think there may be something wrong in my deduction.

Your integration interval is $[0,\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]$, which is related to $n$. So I think the problem may be when you use DCT.

@HeroZhang001 Maybe I should not use change of variables. Then where can we start?

Try integration by parts $\int x'(1-x^2)^n dx$. You will get a recurrence expression.

@Andrei I just found I only needs to add in a characteristic function.

$$
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1/2}\left(1 - x^{2}\right)^{n}{\rm d}x\quad \stackrel{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-nx^{2}}{\rm d}x}
^{\displaystyle Laplace’s\ Method}
$$

$$I_n=\int_{-\frac 12}^{+\frac 12}\sqrt{n} \left(1-x^2\right)^n\,dx=\sqrt{n} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-n;\frac{3}{2};\frac{1
   }{4}\right)$$
$$I_n \sim \sqrt \pi -\frac 2{3n}$$
